# Updating a table in SQL Server with information from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, subquery

I have a "claims" table. Each claim has a client attached to it which is represented by a few letters "ABED". For some reason, the actual clientID is nowhere to be found in the claims table so I want to fix this. The "Clients" table DOES contain both the code AND clientID. How do I run a query where I can update existing claims with the clientID based on the code?

```
UPDATE claims 
SET clientID = (SELECT clientID FROM clients WHERE claimID = code)
```

In the claims table, the code for the client is called "claimID". In the clients table it's called code.

Just to be clear, I did add the clientID column in the claims table, it is currently NULL and I'm looking to fill it with the clientID from the clients table.

Comment: What happens when you run this query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this. more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
update cla
set clientid = (select t.clientid from clients cli where cli.code = cla.claimid)
from claims cla
```

This searches for `clients` whose `code` matches the `claimid` of `claims`, and updates the corresponding `clientid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Clm
SET Clientid = Cnt.Clientid
FROM Claims Clm
JOIN Clients Cnt
ON Clm.Claimid = Cnt.Code
```